# Issue with jquery .css function erratic behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an issue with `jquery .css` function. I am using this to get the actual height of elements whose height is set to auto. Code which i am using is :

```
$(this).css({ height: $(this).css("height"), width: $(this).css("width") });
```

The issue is, the `.css` function sometimes returns `"0px"` sometimes `"auto"` and sometimes actual height (which is the desired behavior). Can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).css("height")` gives you the a defined (or default) value, while `$(this).height()` gives you the *actual*, 'measured' height.

From http://api.jquery.com/height/:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set the height of every matched element.

And from http://api.jquery.com/css/:

> Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).css("height")` will return the set value of the CSS `height` property.

To get the physical height of the element, call `$(this).height()`.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see purpose of your snippet, but using jquery, use that code which at least is cross browser:

```
$(this).css({ height: $(this).height(), width: $(this).width() });
```